# Program that outputs twin prime numbers

Tags: c

I need to write a code that has you input a number and it checks that the given number is a twin prime with the prime number that follows it. Here is what I have so far:

```
int isPrime (int Value){
    int Number;
        for (Number=2; Number <= Value-1; Number++){
        if (Value % Number ==0)
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;
}
}
int nextPrime(int current){
    while (1){
    if (isPrime(current))
        return current;
        current++;
    }
}
int main(){
    int a;
    int First = nextPrime (a);
    int Second = nextPrime(First + 1);
    scanf("%d", &a);
    if (Second - First == 2) {
        printf("%d and %d are twin primes.", First, Second);
    } else {
        printf("%d and %d are not twin primes.", First, Second);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you post what error you are getting or expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stands `a` is uninitialized with the first call to `nextPrime(a)`. To obtain anything other than undefined behavior you would need to read the input value *before* calling `scanf` so it's value has been initialized to the user's input:

```
int a;
int First;
int Second;

scanf("%d", &a); /* move this line before the nextPrime calls */
First = nextPrime (a);
Second = nextPrime(First + 1);
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much! That did it! It works perfect now. It's always something small. I'm new to programming in C and I can't seem to find any help anywhere and I don't understand it that much so I didn't know I had to switch that part of the code around. But thank you so much once again!:)

Comment: @Timmy glad it helped. To make it easier for future readers to know whether they're having a similar problem and have this Q&A help them as well, I suggest you edit your question to include a description of the problem you were having (e.g. "The code compiles, but the program seems to get stuck and never prints anything", or "when I enter an input _X_, I'd expect ... but I get ... instead").